# Remote wiping android application

Tags: android

I am developing an enterprise application where we need to develop a remote wipe feature for our application, is it possible to implement remote wipe for only my application data instead of all personal data of the mobile (I mean I read that we can wipe android device remotely and the device will be set to defaults)?
    Could any body help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a class that will set all variables to default values. Once you receive the wipe request from the service the class will be called and the wipe process will begin. If you have files that are created within the app you would need to keep track of where they are located or in a folder and you can wipe the folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: According to google docs we can use Devise Admin api. But docs are totally messing. If you find any good article how to use device admin api and remote wiping Could you please share with me.